# Nested Multi-Declarations in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Say I have a `Map<String,Pair<String,Any>>`. Can I iterate over all three sub elements directly by using some sort of nested multi-declaration?

```
 for ((key, (k, v)) in map)
```

and

```
 for ((key, k, v) in map)
```

didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nested multi-declarations are not supported in the current version of Kotlin.

As a workaround, you can use a multi-declaration inside the `for`:

```
for ((key, value) in map) {
    val (k, v) = value

    ...
}
```

We are planning to support nested multi-declarations later. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thank you. Kotlin's getting better with every release.